# What do breakpoint numbers mean in Xcode debugger?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

Simple questions but I can't find the answers anywhere.

When Xcode hits a breakpoint, it shows "Thread x: Stopped at breakpoint N" in the right hand margin.  These breakpoint numbers seem nonsensical and I don't know how I would figure out which of my actual breakpoints relate to them.

It's no big deal when a breakpoint is set on a line of code but it gets confusing when I have symbolic breakpoints (which are new to me, by the way).  With a symbolic breakpoint on "tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:" I'm seeing execution breaks at a variety of places that I don't expect - even in the middle of assembly code.

So three questions, really.  1) what do the breakpoint numbers mean and how can I correlate them with my actual breakpoints? 2) is there a way to display breakpoint numbers in the Xcode breakpoint navigator? and 3) am I getting random breaks in execution that I shouldn't be getting - and is there a way to stop that from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: They are just the gdb (or lldb) breakpoint numbers - you can list them in the debug console using "info break".

Comment: Thanks Paul R.  Very helpful.  I still don't know why I'm seeing some of the odd breaks that I am but I'll keep digging.  If I figure that out I'll answer my own question.